# How to get around variant apply_visitor not supporting 3 args?

Tags: c++, boost, variant

For some reason, using boost's variant(I know there is a c++17 version, I'm providing backwards compatibility here, and plus c++17 isn't fully supported by clang++ yet) leads to some strange behavior when using the visitor paradigm:

## 2 arguments, works

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

using boost::variant;

typedef boost::variant<double, std::string> term_t;

class plus_visitor : public boost::static_visitor<term_t> {
public:
    term_t operator()(double lhs, double rhs) const{
        return {lhs + rhs};
    }
    term_t operator()(double lhs, std::string rhs) const{
        return {lhs + std::stoi(rhs)};
    }
    term_t operator()(std::string lhs, int rhs) const{
        return operator()(rhs, lhs);
    }
    term_t operator()(std::string lhs, std::string rhs) const{
        return std::stoi(lhs) + std::stoi(rhs);
    }
};

int main(){
    // term_t lhs {3.0};
    term_t rhs {"10"};
    term_t lhs {"3"};
    term_t res = boost::apply_visitor(plus_visitor(), lhs, rhs);
    std::cout << res << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It outputs 13 as expected.

## 3 arguments, explodes

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

using boost::variant;

typedef boost::variant<double, std::string> term_t;

class plus_visitor : public boost::static_visitor<term_t> {
public:
    term_t operator()(double lhs, double rhs, double x) const{
        return {lhs + rhs + x};
    }
    term_t operator()(double lhs, std::string rhs, double x) const{
        return {lhs + std::stoi(rhs) + x};
    }
    term_t operator()(std::string lhs, double rhs, double x) const{
        return operator()(rhs, lhs, x);
    }
    term_t operator()(std::string lhs, std::string rhs, double x) const{
        return std::stoi(lhs) + std::stoi(rhs) + x;
    }
};

int main(){
    term_t rhs {"10"};
    term_t lhs {"3"};
    term_t x {3.0};
    term_t res = boost::apply_visitor(plus_visitor(), lhs, rhs, x);
    std::cout << res << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What's the deal here? Does `apply_visitor` only work for 2 arguments?

## Diagnosis

I looked to the documentation and found that:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/boost/apply_visitor.html

`apply_visitor` works only for binary arguments or unary arguments! This sucks! How can I work around this and supply a 3rd one without being completely ugly in the syntax? Is there another `boost` library function that allows more inputs? Why does the boost library not use variadic templates to allow for arbitrary sized `apply_visitor` functions?

Comment: BTW, you forgot lot of overloads (the ones where 3rd parameter is `std::string`)

Comment: @Jarod42 I know. I'm just trying to prove a point here

Comment: Well, point proven. If you want to use boost, you'll have to deal with the limitation. If you need more than two arguments, replace them with a single structure, containing as many values as you wish.

Comment: With updated version, it is avalaible: 
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost/apply_visitor.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at documentation for Boost 1.36, which was [released in 2008](http://www.boost.org/users/history/). If you look at the [documentation for the current release](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost/apply_visitor.html), it lists the following `apply_visitor` overloads

```
template<typename MultiVisitor, typename Variant1, typename Variant2, 
         typename Variant3> 
  typename MultiVisitor::result_type OR decltype(auto) 
  apply_visitor(MultiVisitor & visitor, Variant1 & operand1, 
                Variant2 & operand2, Variant3 & operand3, ... other_operands);
template<typename MultiVisitor, typename Variant1, typename Variant2, 
         typename Variant3> 
  typename MultiVisitor::result_type OR decltype(auto) 
  apply_visitor(const MultiVisitor & visitor, Variant1 & operand1, 
                Variant2 & operand2, Variant3 & operand3, ... other_operands);
```

The documentation also states

> Overloads accepting three or more operands invoke the function call operator of the given visitor on the content of the given variant operands. ... **Those functions are actually defined in a header `boost/variant/multivisitors.hpp`** ... **That header must be manually included if multi visitors are meant for use.**

So make sure you're using a recent Boost release, include the relevant header, define the missing `operator()` overloads for the 3 argument example and your code should compile.

Comment: Got it. Thank you! I wish they could make this a little bit more visible. Also, it's extremely hard to read the error messages in this boost lib. :(

Comment: @OneRaynyDay Google searches rarely turn up the latest Boost release documentation, but if you're looking at old documentation, there will be a yellow box at the top that says you're not looking at the latest release and has a link for the latest docs (although that link is broken in some cases :))